# Fragments overlap when replacing basic fragments and their layouts

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout, android-fragments

I'll go straight to the problem. What am I doing wrong when replacing fragments in Android? The expected result when I clicked on Sponsors:

[image]

The reality(what I actually got: basically, it just the Sponsors fragment, which just lays on Other fragment):

[image]

I'm  calling a fragment by

```
fragment = new Other(this);
```

Sponsors.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:text="Sponsors" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Sponsors.java

```
    ...
    public class Sponsors extends android.support.v4.app.Fragment {
    private Context context;

    public Sponsors(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.sponsors, null);
        return rootView;
    }
}
```

other.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/other_frame_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@android:color/white">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="COMMON"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textColor="@color/header_red"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp" />
        <View
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="2dp"
            android:background="@color/header_red"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/sponsors"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Sponsors"
            android:textColor="@color/subtext"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:paddingTop="15dp"
            android:paddingBottom="15dp"
            android:paddingLeft="15dp" />
</LinearLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

Other.java

```
public class Other extends android.support.v4.app.Fragment {
public Other(Context context) {
    this.context = context;
}
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.other, container, false);
    sponsors = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.sponsors);
sponsors.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (savedInstanceState == null) {
                Sponsors duedateFrag = new Sponsors();
                FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                ft.add(R.id.other_frame_container, duedateFrag);
                ft.addToBackStack(null);
                ft.commit();
            }
        }
    });
    }
```

Comment: Why are you adding your Sponsors `Fragment` in the `onCreateView(...)` method of your Others `Fragment`? Unless you're using nested `Fragments`, no individual `Fragment` should know about or manipulate any other `Fragment`. Creation, adding, replacing, removing of `Fragments` should be done by the `Activity`.

Answer (score 3):

Change `add` to `replace` in `FragmentTransaction`

```
FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
ft.replace(R.id.other_frame_container, duedateFrag);
```